# Symfony Swiftmail use with yahoo

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, roundcube

I want to send an email with Symfony SwiftMail and a Gandi (roundcube) adress.
The problem is that nothing happen and I don't know why. ^^

config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: mail
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    host:      smtp
    username:  'my email'
    password:  'my mdp'
```

parametres.yml

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1:160
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
```

Controller:

```
public function contactAction()
{
    $mail = "mymail";
    $enquiry = new Contact();
    $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request);
        $data = $form->getData();

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setContentType('text/html')
            ->setSubject($data->getSubject())
            ->setFrom($data->getAdresse())
            ->setTo($mail)
            ->setBody($data->getMessage());
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('st_contact_homepage'));
    }
    return $this->render('STCommonBundle:Default:contact.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your config seems to be wrong

the "host" property must be the smpt hostname

sth like

```
smpt.yahoo.com
```

you need to find it out

and the transport is smpt

so rather like that :

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: smtp
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    host:      smtp.yahoo.com
    username:  'my email'
    password:  'my mdp'
```

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply, I've been able to work this with your advice.
My misstake was to use a generic host, not the one from the service (yahoo/google/...).